# How can I use regular expressions with Doctrine's Mongodb ODM?

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm trying to use regular expressions to query Mongodb using Doctrine's Mongodb ODM on Symfony 2.

I know the [PHP mongo driver can do it](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php). However, I don't know how to do this with Doctrine.

Do I use the same class? How do I reference MongoRegex from within Symfony?

Comment: For someone who don't wont to use the MongoRegex as that was deprecated can try this solution
MongoRegex has been depecated as per the 

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36761669/symfony2-need-to-use-the-regular-expression-in-doctrines-mongodb-odm-to-check

That is why I have given this answer for those who may have concern about this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This came up a while ago on the [doctrine-user](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/doctrine-user/2q204wMMGWw/CPUEM8TdDxMJ) mailing list. You can use the `\MongoRegex` class directly in your ODM queries:

```
$documentRepository->findBy(array(
    'foo' => new \MongoRegex('/^bar/'),
));
```

Or if using a query builder:

```
$queryBuilder->field('foo')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/^bar/'));
```

Keep in mind that front-anchored, case-sensitive regex patterns will be able to use indexes most efficiently. This is discussed in more detail in the [Mongo docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).

Comment: I need to use new MongoDB\BSON\Regex class as MongoRegex is deperecated now. How can I use this in Symfony2 project.
var_dump($regex);
http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-regex.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the Question on stack overflow for detail
[How to use Reserved characters in createQueryBuilder and MongoRegix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007147/how-to-use-reserved-characters-in-createquerybuilder-and-mongoregix/19026467#19026467),

Additionally, while /^a/, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ match equivalent strings, they have different performance characteristics. All of these expressions use an index if an appropriate index exists; however, /^a.*/, and /^a.*$/ are slower. /^a/ can stop scanning after matching the prefix.
[Mongo Docs Regix](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/)

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer by jmikola is completely correct but as the `\MongoRegex` class is deprecated in newer versions of Doctrine, the new approach would be to use `\MongoDB\BSON\Regex` class. For example, in query builder approach, you may use:

```php
$queryBuilder->field('foo')->equals(new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex('^bar'));
```

Note that unlike MongoRegex class, here the pattern should not be wrapped with delimiter characters.