# How to use Reserved characters in createQueryBuilder and MongoRegix

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, odm

i'm doing search with ZF2 Doctrine2 ODM and using MongoRegix but the problem is that i'm not able to search those terms which contains brackets like BS(Hons) is not searchable. my query is

```
$q->addOr($q->expr()->field($columns[$i]['field'])->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*BS(Hons).*/i')));
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Parantehsis are assumed to be used for Grouping in Doctrine you can check refrence http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

Comment: if i m not wrong brackets () are used for the grouping in ORM, does it also implies on ODM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved characters can be used in MongoRegx in the way.

```
/.*BS/(Hons/).*/i
```

the Query will be like this

```
$q->addOr($q->expr()->field($field)->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*BS/(Hons/).*/i')));
```

Comment: so passing (Hons/) wont cause to be read as BS(Hons) +1 if it works